# ObservableCollection обновление UI

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

В модели есть коллекция объектов:

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> _groupedTransactions = null;
public ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> groupedTransactions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_groupedTransactions == null)
            {
                _groupedTransactions = DBManager.getGroupedTransactions();
            }
            return _groupedTransactions;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupedTransactions = value;
        }
    }
```

Когда я добавляю\изменяю\удаляю элементы по одному то все ок, в `ListView` сразу же отображаются изменения, но когда мне нужно полностью обновить коллекцию:

```
private async void Signals_NeedRefreshTransEvent()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            groupedTransactions = DBManager.getGroupedTransactions();
        });
    }
```

То `ListView` не изменяется, и перестанет реагировать на будущие изменения. Как заставить его обновить UI не обновляя источник в коде формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта я вижу два:

1. В `set` коллекции вызывать реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. `set` сделать приватным, вместо перебивки использовать `Clear` и `AddRange`(которого по умолчанию нет, писать придётся отдельно).

Первый вариант очевиднее и проще.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сам уже все это попробовал )) 1) не вариант, ибо не работает (скорее всего при присваивании теряется ссылка на коллекцию и единственный вариант ее перебиндить). 2) Работает, вызываю `Clear`, а затем `foreach` и `add` - не самое лучшее решение конечно но пока сойдет. В будущем мб перепишу под сравнение каждого элемента и обновление\вставка при надобности (хотя и не факт что выйдет лучше)

Comment: @SYL если свойство `groupedTransactions` биндится на `ItemsSource` у `ListView`, то и первый вариант должен работать.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, однако не работает